# How to find chromes client area and dimensions (excluding the omnibox drop down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to find the dimensions of chromes client area excluding the omnibox drop down.

Im writing a chrome extension that listens to the omnibox-events and popping up a custom div, i would like the div to display at the bottom of the omnibox dropdown window.

Note : i know i can display suggestions, however that's not what i'm trying to achieve

Is this possible?

my alternatives are

set the divs **top** to some arbitrary pixel height to offset the dropdown (this seems fraught with issues)

set the divs **bottom** to 0px (not ascetically pleasing)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, not possible without some *serious* hackery. That is because the omnibar dropdown does not in any way affect the rendering window, and so its coordinates are visible only to Chrome (software) itself, not to the client-side site.

You can try `document.getClientRects()` to get the size of the render screen; this might help you down the line when trying to 'guess' the size of the omnibar dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width of the currently visible area you should do like that :

```
jQuery(document).width() - jQuery(window).width()
```

and to get the height :

```
jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()
```

once on browser load you just set the position of your div based on this height & width.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this value doesn't change with the omnibox drop down open, i'm starting to think its not possible